# Proof that the product of powers of the same base is that base raised to the sum of the exponents

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is it possible to prove that $$a^xa^y=a^{x+y}$$ with only the following exponentiation properties: $a^0=1$, $a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$ and $a^{-n}=(a^{n})^{-1}$? All the properties of the product and of the sum of integers may be used (I forgot to mention, $a, x, y, n$ are integers). If one is to use the property $a^{n+1}=a^{n}a^{1}$, one must prove first this property by means of the aforementioned facts.
I'm asking because I'm stuck at an exercise that asks me this.

Comment: If I don't have the property $a^{n+1} = a^n a^1$, what would forbid me to redefine exponentiation (for $a\ne 0$) as

$$a^n = \begin{cases}
\frac1a, & n= -1\\
1, & n=0\\
a, & n=1\\
-1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
?

Comment: In other words: what is your definition of $a^n$ for $n\ge2?$

Comment: So, I thought it was not possible to prove, I thought the same thing as @peterwhy, but couldn't find another definition different from that of the exponentiation that would also satisfy the properties above. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

If $a^0=1, a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$, then $a^0=a^{-1}*a$. That only proves it for that one case, but you didn't provide enough properties to evaluate $a^2$ in terms of *a*, so I think that's good enough.

From said property, we know that $a^n=a*a^{n-1}$. Let's say $x, y \in Z$, and define $a^{x+y}$. We know that it equals $a^{x+y-1}*a$. We can repeat this process until we find that $a^{x+y-y}*a. . .y. . . a*a$. Then, we can use the inverse property and turn the repeated multiplication into $a^x*a^y=a^{x+y}$.

Moreover, since the only property of integers we used was the repeated multiplication, and that was washed away, it works for $x, y\in R$.

(I'm aware the proof wasn't rigorous, but with the limited properties we were allowed to use, it really couldn't have been.)

Comment: I don't agree. I believe it is not possible to define the exponentiation operation with only the properties I mentioned in my question. This relation $a^n=a*a^{n-1}$ is only valid for n=1, from said properties only you may not extend it to any other value of n.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach for future reference.

We define the exponential function as the power series:
\begin{align*}
\exp(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \ldots
\end{align*}
which converges absolutely on the real line (in order to conclude so, apply the ratio test, for example).

Since we are dealing with absolute convergence, one has that
\begin{align*}
\exp(a)\exp(b) & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a^{k}}{k!}\frac{b^{n - k}}{(n - k)!}\\\\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}a^{k}b^{n - k}\\\\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a + b)^{n}}{n!}\\\\
& = \exp(a + b)
\end{align*}

Clearly, $\exp(x) > 0$ when $x\geq 0$. Let $x < 0$. Since $\exp(0) = 1$, one has that:
\begin{align*}
\exp(x)\exp(-x) = \exp(0) = 1 \Rightarrow \exp(x) = \frac{1}{\exp(-x)} > 0
\end{align*}

Since $\exp'(x) = \exp(x) > 0$, we conclude the exponential function is continuous and strictly increasing. Consequently, it admits an inverse which is also continuous and strictly increasing. Such function is usually denoted by $\ln:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Based on such considerations, one defines the exponential function as $a^{x} := \exp(x\ln(a))$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\backslash\{1\}$, whence we deduce the desired property as follows:
\begin{align*}
a^{x}a^{y} & = \exp(x\ln(a))\exp(y\ln(a))\\\\
& = \exp(x\ln(a) + y\ln(a))\\\\
& = \exp((x + y)\ln(a)) = a^{x + y}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Why the downvote?